# Having symbol on top of the baseline and below at the same time

Tags: overset

What i try to achieve is to mark page breaks of two previous editions within the text. Basically edition A gets a little corner on the top, and edition B one below. This works except for the font sizes – if the font size changes, the symbol size changes as well, which shouldn't be.

And then another problem arises from that: If the font size is fixed, i can't use `\lcorners` any more but have to change to `\overset` and `\underset`, I guess. But how to position them correctly so that they are horizontally aligned?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\pb}[1]{\ifstrequal{#1}{A}
    {$\textstyle\ulcorner\kern-.1em$}
    {\ifstrequal{#1}{B}
        {$\textstyle\llcorner\kern-.1em$}
    {$\textstyle\lcorners\kern-.1em$}}}

\begin{document}


\Large \pb{A}Test \pb{B}Test

\normalsize \pb{A}Test \pb{B}Test

And now both of them together:

\Large \pb{AB}Test

\normalsize \pb{AB}Test


\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve the size problem using `\normalsize`; the upper corner is first lowered to the baseline, then raised to the height of a capital letter plus 2pt. The double corners are obtained overprinting the upper corner over the lower corner.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newcommand{\pb}[1]{\csname pb#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\pbA}{%
  \raisebox{\Theight}{\raisebox{-\height}{\normalsize$\ulcorner$}}%
}
\newcommand{\pbB}{{\normalsize$\llcorner$}}
\newcommand{\pbAB}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\pbB}\pbA}
\newcommand{\Theight}{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`T+2pt}

\begin{document}


\Large \pb{A}Test \pb{B}Test

\normalsize \pb{A}Test \pb{B}Test

And now both of them together:

\Large \pb{AB}Test

\normalsize \pb{AB}Test

\end{document}
```

[image]